# Regular expressions remove everything between <>

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, gsub

I am learning to web scrape. I have got hold of a bunch of data but of a messy structure.
I have a vector of strings of this form:
`"9,55< U+00A0>x< U+00A0>1016"`, (now when I am writing it I think it is a special syntax, because I cannot paste it here without putting a space before the "U")
 which on the website I am scraping from is written as "9,55*10^16".

My goal in the long run, is to turn this string into a numeric variable, i.e. 95500000000000000.
But first I want to remove everything between the first "<" and the last ">". 
Below is my attempt.

```
gsub("<(.*?)>", "", vectorOfStrings)
```

**Edit**: the string is best generated in R using `"9,55\U{00A0}x\U{00A0}1016"`, since the "<" and ">" are not actual literals in the string.

Comment: What language is this? What's gsub()?

Comment: @MrJLP: it's the "R" language. `gsub` is a regular-expression search/replace function.

Comment: If your using php do preg_replace javascript do //g something to note is that sometimes they dont do < and > but &lt; and &gt; Maybe for the R language you need to do //g

Comment: It's the [R programming language](https://www.r-project.org/), not PHP.

Comment: So try gsub("/<(.*?)>/g", "", vecorOfSrings)  //g stands for global

Comment: TKN, what some answers/comments are missing is that the "<" and ">" are R representations of unicode and not actually in the character string. Because it is an R-specific representation, any answer here that actually looks for those chars will probably not fit your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The characters your seeing are unicode (UTF-8, I think), and R's representation (when it is not abundantly clear) is the less-than/greater-than notation. To remove it, one method is to "convert" the text to ASCII:

```
iconv(vectorOfStrings, "utf-8", "ASCII", sub = "")
```

Anything non-translatable should be dropped.

Comment: Yepp thats it! :D
I was thinking that it was something like that since I could not write it in correct form in my question. SO transformed it to the "correct" structure automatically.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would simply change your greedy "Match all" to "Match all but '>' like, or use .? to make it lazy (match minimum)

```
<[^>]*> or <.*?>
```

or to match tag to tag

```
<.*?>.*?<.*?>
```

Comment: That would do if it was just a regular string, but in my case it was different :( Please see @r2evans solution.

Comment: @TKN I'll leave it encase someone come here looking for the text version based on question title =P

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
>vectorOfStrings = "9,55< U+00A0>x< U+00A0>1016"
>vectorOfStrings1 = gsub("<[^>]+>","",vectorOfStrings)
>vectorOfStrings1 
[1] "9,55x1016"
```

Comment: That would do if it was just a regular string, but in my case it was different :(
Please see @r2evans solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code to scrape the scientific notation number, from the web, to numeric:

```
library(magrittr)

vectorOfStrings <- "9,55< U+00A0>x< U+00A0>1016"  

scrape_numeric <- function(x) {
 x %>% 
   gsub(">10", ">e+", .) %>%
   gsub("<.*>", "", .) %>%
   gsub(",", ".", .) %>%
   as.numeric
}

scrape_numeric(vectorOfStrings)

# [1] 9.55e+16
```